# Why does swift viewDidLoad() ignore my "return" statement?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The following code ignores the first "return" and runs the code after the return, causing crash.   Output at bottom...

```
override func viewDidLoad()              ///////////////////////////////////////// VIEW DID LOAD
{
    print("viewDidLoad...")
    // Init app:
        App_class.print_time()
        super.viewDidLoad()

    // Init mapper...
        view.addSubview( ViewController.wrist_band_UIImageView )

    // Init client socket to hub socket service:
           print("viewDidLoad  Init client socket to hub socket service")
           let client_socket_instance = Client_Socket_class()
           client_socket_instance.init_()


    // Connect to hub socket...
           print("viewDidLoad  Connect to hub socket 192.168.7.109 port 11111")
        client_socket_instance.connect_to_service( IP_address: "192.168.7.109", port_number: "11111"  )

    // Send commumcation preamble COM FMT VER:
        client_socket_instance.send( message: "rev1")
        // (hub responds and starts stream of location xy packets)

    // Idle this thread while socket event callback processes each packet from hub:
    print("viewDidLoad  Ready to process location data from hub...")
    return
    print(" WOW, it ignored 'return'.")


    // Start mapper...
        print("viewDidLoad  DispatchQueue.global().async{ App_class.run_app_main() }")

        // This is main UI thread running.
        // Have global queue run run_app:
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async
        { 
            App_class.run_app()
            //App_class.run_app_main()
        }

    print("viewDidLoad done.")
    return   
}
```

}

CONSOLE OUTPUT...

```
viewDidLoad...
Time:  2021-May-08 15:49:38.133
viewDidLoad  Init client socket to hub socket service
viewDidLoad  Connect to hub socket 192.168.7.109 port 11111
Opening streams.
func stream  stream event NSStreamEvent(rawValue: 1)
Stream opened
func stream  stream event NSStreamEvent(rawValue: 4)
Stream has space available now
viewDidLoad  Ready to process location data from hub...
 WOW, it ignored 'return'.
(lldb)
```

[image]

Comment: just curious, how do you plan to execute code below the first return?

Answer (score 3):

Add a semicolon after return...

`return;`

Otherwise, `print` command is interpreted as a parameter for return.

Comment: And how does that explain the crash?

Comment: Well probably because the print is interpreted as a parameter for the return in a function (viewDidLoad) that does not have a return statement.

Comment: This answer seems like a "shot in the dark."  Even if print is interpreted as a parameter of return, the return should still execute, yes?

Comment: "Shot in the dark" ? The compiler produce a warning: "Expression following 'return' is treated as an argument of the 'return'" ... As for "why the return is not interpreted", maybe because the function have Void() as return parameter, so not interpreted with a parameter ? It's better to ask on the swift forum... I'm just giving facts, not explaining "why it's works like this". Adding a semicolon fix your problem of "return not interpreted", and for the crash, without the source or more context, i don't know.